# Pattern match on abstract type

Tags: scala, reflection, pattern-matching

```
trait Aggregate {
    type Command
}

class AggregateHandler(a: Aggregate) {
   def receiveCommand: Receive = {
     case a.Command => ???
   }
}
```

How can I pattern match on a.Command? I am getting; `abstract type pattern AggregateHandler.this.a.Command is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure` and `The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time.`

How can I workaround this?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Seems like you are trying to apply DDD with some akka-persistence related stuff. In that case, it would be better to have `Command` as a `case class`. Please, clarify.

Comment: `Command` is a case class or an object in the end. However that is not the question in this case. It's just an example to showoff what I want to achieve.

Comment: A self-contained example (that compiles to the extent of demonstrating the error) is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

For example, this `Aggregate#A` has an `outer` field that points to the enclosing instance of `Aggregate`.

```
trait Aggregate {
  //type A
  class A
}

class AggregateHandler(a: Aggregate) {
  def f: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case _: a.A => ()
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  class X extends Aggregate {
    //type A = Int
    val x: A = new A
  }
  val x = new X
  val h = new AggregateHandler(x)
  h.f(x.x)
}
```

Comment: I guess this would work, however I don't want to bring the classes inside the implementation of the trait